# How to use scrollTop() inside a loop with delays correctly?

Tags: javascript, html

So I am wondering why inside scrollInSteps all the scrolling is basically executed at once (atleast it seems like it since nothing is ever printed, and the scrollbar directly jumps to the last positon)

What I would like is the scrollbar to jump every 0.5 seconds to its next position.
But somehow this does not work at all.

Does anybody have an Idea on why the scroll behaviour is only applied, when the loop basically is finished?

And how can I change this?

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  const date = Date.now();
  let currentDate = null;
  do {
    currentDate = Date.now();
  } while (currentDate - date < milliseconds);
}

function scrollInSteps(){
  console.log("BUTTON CLICKED");
    let counter = 0;
    while(counter <= 10){
    sleep(500);
    counter++;
    console.log("SCROLL");
        $(".demo").scrollTop($(".demo").prop('scrollTop')+100);
    }
}

function scrollOnce(){
  console.log("BUTTON CLICKED");
  console.log($(".demo").prop('scrollTop'));
  $(".demo").scrollTop($(".demo").prop('scrollTop')+100);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>scrollTop demo</title>
  <style>
  div.demo {
    background: #ccc none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border: 3px solid #666;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  p {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 2px solid #666;
    height: 100px;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="demo">
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
<button onClick="scrollOnce()">SCROLL ONCE</button>
<button onClick="scrollInSteps()">SCROLL IN STEPS</button>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no sleep function by default, but you can create one using async/await and Promises.

```js
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve,time));
}
```

Then all you have to do change your scrollInSteps function to be an async function, so that you can 'await' the sleep time.

```js
async function scrollInSteps(){
  console.log("BUTTON CLICKED");
  for (let counter = 0; counter < 10; counter++) {
    await sleep(500); // will pause until the promise is resolved
    console.log("SCROLL");
    $(".demo").scrollTop($(".demo").prop('scrollTop')+100);
  }
}
```

Comment: dope! thanks! But why doesn`t it work with my own sleep() function?? I mean...everything is executed sequentially, and therefor it seems weird to me that not even the logs appear until the very end...

Comment: @DigitalJedi see my answer below for an explanation of _why_ your original code doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are blocking the [main thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Main_thread), which doesn't give the browser a chance to redraw the screen.

Let's say I have the following code (just for a demo, do not write something like this on a real website):

```js
function main() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  // Loop 100 times
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    container.innerHTML = i;
  }
}

main();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

If I run this, you don't see the numbers 1-100 render on the screen. Instead, it just "immediately" shows the number `100`. Why is that?

Because [JavaScript runs on a single thread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), so while each iteration of that code is running, the browser doesn't have an opportunity to redraw the screen.

You essentially are doing the same thing. Your `sleep` function is all synchronous: it just runs a (potentially) infinite loop as a way to pause execution. **This is an extremely bad practice**, for the reasons that you are noticing. While the main thread is blocked, *nothing else can happen*!

Instead, you want to run these "steps" in an [asynchronous manner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous) so that the browser can do things in the time between those async things.

A common "sleep" function in modern JavaScript looks like this

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve();
    }, milliseconds);
  });
}

// Alternatively, in modern JS we'd write
const sleep = (milliseconds) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), milliseconds));
```

Here, we are returning a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that will resolve after a `millisecond` delay via [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

By using this function and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function), we can easily run things in an asynchronous manner while still writing like we do with synchronous code.

With my previous example, now if I write:

```js
const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));

// Function must be `async` so we can `await` within
async function main() {
  const container = document.getElementById('container');

  // Loop 100 times
  for (let i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    // Wait 5 milliseconds
    await sleep(5);
    container.innerHTML = i;
  }
}

main();
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Now running the above, we see the numbers increment from 1 to 100.

You'll want to make similar changes to your code.